# Kerberos on Windows8

Tags: security, hadoop, kerberos

**Can anyone help me to setup kerberos authentication on windows8?**

1.I googled about kerberos setup in windows8, but it is hard to know,

2.Also tried with Ksetup command line tool, but there is no improvements,

Help me to setup kerberos in windows8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I too struck into the same. If you got any solution or idea please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I tried with MIT Kerberos's windows distribution from this link http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/#kfw-4.0.

But there is no proper user guide regarding its usage.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Kerberos in windows can be achieved by the **windows server OS** with **active directory**
2. In that server we need to create krb5.ini configuration file and users who are going to be access the service or host
3. Also we need to map separate principals to the appropriate user
4. Finally we can access those principals in any other windows system with the correct kerberos realm

Refer [Configuring Windows Server 2000 Kerberos Service](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.security/kerberos_configuring_windows_server2000_kerberos_service.htm%23kerberos_configuring_windows_server2000_kerberos_service)